# Does $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin n}{n}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n})$ converge (absolutely)?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've had no luck with this one. None of the convergence tests pop into mind.

I tried looking at it in this form $\sum \sin n\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{n}$ and apply Dirichlets test. I know that $\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{n} \to 0$ but not sure if it's decreasing.

Regarding absolute convergence, I tried:

$$|\sin n\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{n}|\geq \sin^2 n\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{n}=$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{n}-\frac{1}{2}\cos 2n\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{n}$$

But again I'm stuck with $\cos 2n\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{n}$.
Assuming it converges then I've shown that $\sum \sin n\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{n}$ doesn't converge absolutely.

Comment: Perhaps there's something useful to be done with the fact that $\log n<1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}<\log n+1$?

Comment: Also, Mathematica seems to think that it does in fact converge, giving a result of `1/2 I E^-I (E^I EulerGamma Log[1-E^I]-E^I EulerGamma Log[(-1+E^I) E^-I]-(Hypergeometric2F1Regularized^(0,0,1,0))[1,1,2,E^-I]+E^(2 I) (Hypergeometric2F1Regularized^(0,0,1,0))[1,1,2,E^I])`, which is approximately $1.05895$.

Comment: Just a comment, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n}{n} = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{2}$$Maybe this might help...

Comment: My older copy (5.2) of *Mathematica* yields the result $$\frac{i}{2}\left(\mathrm{Li}_2\left(1+\frac1{\exp(i)-1}\right)-\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac1{1-\exp(i)}\right)\right)$$ where $\mathrm{Li}_2(x)$ is the dilogarithm. Numerically, it agrees with @Isaac's result. I am away from my refs so I cannot analytically prove the equivalence of the two.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The sequence $$a_n=\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}}{n}$$ is decreasing because proving $a_{n+1}<a_n$ reduces to proving $$\frac{n}{n+1}<1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}$$ which is clearly true.

Also the sums $$s_k=\sum_{n=1}^k \sin n$$ are bounded. (This can be easily proved by writing $\sin n$ in its complex form and using finite geometric formula; in fact $|s_k|$ are bounded by $\frac{1}{|1-e^i|}+\frac{1}{|1-e^{-i}|}$).

Furthermore $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ because $1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}\approx \log n$.

So the series converges by Dirichlet test. As Shai shows below, the convergence is not absolute.

Comment: Are you sure about that first claim? I'm convinced that sequence is indeed decreasing, but I don't see how it reduces to the inequality you have there.

Comment: Just write out $a_{n+1}<a_n$ and multiply both sides by $n(n+1)$.

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks. =)

Answer (score 14):

To show that the series does not converge absolutely, it suffices to show that $\sum\nolimits_{n = 1}^\infty  {|\frac{{\sin n}}{n}|}  = \infty $. For this purpose, see [this](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/99/series): the paragraph starting with "It's not absolutely convergent" as well as the one starting with "This series exhibits rather irregular behaviour" (two different approaches).

Comment: How does one show the two inequalities needed on the page you referenced? $\min(|\sin(n)|,|\sin(n+1)|) \geq m > 0$ and $|\sin(x)| + |\sin(x-1)| \geq \sin(1)$

Comment: @admchrch: thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @admchrch: For the first, there should have been $\max$ instead of $\min$; for the second, at least it can be confirmed by plotting the difference $|\sin(x)| + |\sin(x-1)| - \sin(1)$.

Comment: The method that uses the first bound is invalid if it is max instead of min.  I guess the second can be proved by considering the functions $\sin(x) + \sin(x-1) - \sin(1)$, $\sin(x) - \sin(x-1) - \sin(1)$, $-\sin(x) + \sin(x-1) - \sin(1)$, and $-\sin(x) - \sin(x-1) - \sin(1)$ in appropriate regions and using calculus.  A more elegant method of proof does not occur to me.

Comment: To disprove absolute convergence, I noted $|\sin n| \geq \sin^2 n = \frac{1}{2}( 1 - \cos 2n )$ and used Dirichlet's test to show $\sum \frac{\cos 2n}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: I suspect it is true that $|\sin n| \geq m > 0$, but I think the proof requires some nontrivial number theory.

Comment: @admchrch: For the first method, what's wrong if it is $\max$ instead of $\min$?

Comment: @Shai: Perhaps I am missing something.  Doesn't the first method work by asserting $$\frac{|\sin n|}{n} \geq \frac{\min(|\sin n|, |\sin(n-1)|)}{n} \geq \frac{m}{n}$$ and deducing divergence by comparison with the harmonic series?  The first inequality is reversed if it is max instead of min.

Comment: @admchrch: The first method works thanks to $\frac{{|\sin n|}}{n} + \frac{{|\sin (n + 1)|}}{{n + 1}} \ge \frac{{|\sin n| + |\sin (n + 1)|}}{{n + 1}} \ge \frac{m}{{n + 1}}$.

Comment: @admchrch: Concerning a previous comment, $\lim \inf _{n \to \infty } |\sin n| = 0$.

Comment: @Shai: You are right, it is not true that $|\sin n|≥m>0$.

Comment: @Shai: Okay I see it now:
$$|\sin(n)| + |\sin(n+1)| \geq \max(|\sin(n)|,|\sin(n+1)|)$$
Thanks.

Comment: This also follows easily from a Dirichlet approximation type Theorem. More exactly, because $2\pi$ is irrational, one can show that there exists an $N$ so that among any $N$ consecutive integers we can find an $n$ with $\sin(n) \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Link's down....