# Does the sum $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{\sin\left(n\right)}{n}\sum _{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\:\right)$ absolutely converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have the following sum:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{\sin\left(n\right)}{n}\sum _{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\:\right)$$

And I need to determine if it absolutely converges, conditionally converges or diverges.

I know it converges conditionally with the help of the Dirichlet test, but I'm having a hard time determining if it converges absolutely.
Intuitively, I have a feeling it does not, because $\left|\frac{\sin\left(n\right)}{n}\right|$ looks to be partial to the harmonic sum, which diverges.

Comment: Do you know that $\sum\frac{\sin n}{n}$ isn't absolutely convergent?

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15984/does-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-sin-nn1-frac12-cdots-frac1n

Answer (score 2):

$$ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\sin\left(n\right)}{n}\sum _{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\:\right| \ge  \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left|\frac{\sin\left(n\right)}{n}\:\right|$$
We know that the right side does not converge hence the series does not converge.

Comment: why doesn't the RHS converge?

Comment: @Alex $|\sin(x)|\ge \sin^2(x)$ using this inequality, you get $$ \frac{|\sin (n)|}{n} \ge \frac{\sin^2 (n)}{n} = \frac{1 - \cos 2n}{2n}$$

Comment: @Alex
$\frac{\cos 2n}{2n}$ converges by the same test that works for $\frac{\sin n }{n}$ i.e. Dirichlet Test, while the $\frac 1 n$ does not converge by integral test, Hence it does not converge by comparison test.

Comment: OK thanks, I understand now (I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: @Alex I don't mind downvote ... besides my original answer was pretty stupid :( didn't think enough before I posted :((

Comment: That's OK. I hope the downvoter will remove it.

Comment: haha ... thank you very much :D