# Does $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin(n)}{n}\left ( \sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m} \right )\right) $ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I am trying to determine whether the

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin(n)}{n}\left ( \sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m} \right ) \right) 
$$

converges or not. I have tried the popular tests, but all were inconclusive (so perhaps I am doing it wrong...).

I would appreciate any help and explanation on how I should solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812455/does-the-sum-sum-n-1-infty-left-frac-sin-leftn-rightn-sum-k-1

Comment: The first answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15984/does-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-sin-nn1-frac12-cdots-frac1n may be better for convergence as opposed to absolute convergence