# When does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n^p}$ absolutely converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $p>0$. I must find the values of $p$ for which the following series converges: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n^p}$$ I have already successfully proven the following estimate by induction: $$\sin 1+ \cdots+ \sin n=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12\right)}$$ But this means that the sequence $\sin 1 +\cdots + \sin n$ is bounded for all $n$. Then, the original series converges if $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty=\frac{1}{n^p}$ is a decreasing sequence of positive numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}=0$. Then, $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges for all $p>0$, as this is the the only scenario which fulfills both conditions.

I have used the following theorem:

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_na_n$ be an infinite sequence such that:

1. The sequence $B_n=b_1+\cdots+b_n$ is bounded.
2. $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a decreasing sequence of positive numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$

Then, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_na_n$ is converging.

Now, when would $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n^p}$ converge absolutely? We would then have to find the values of $p$ for which the following converges: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lvert \sin n\rvert}{n^p}$$ Would I still be able to use my original estimate for $\sin n$? If so, the answer would be the same as above, but I am not certain how to determine this.

Edit: While graphing variations of this, it seems that the above series converges for all $p>1$. Is there a formal way I can show that this is true?

Comment: What theorem are you quoting to say the product converges?

Comment: I have added the theorem to the original post.

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with what you've done; I suppose you could check by using summation by parts directly on the given sequence.

Comment: Theorem you are using is [Dirichlet's Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) but we would say the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is monotonically decreasing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the sum of sin(n)/n convergent or divergent?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36732/is-the-sum-of-sinn-n-convergent-or-divergent)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification regarding my original post; it seems I was just confused with how the question was formulated. I have added another query, however, regarding absolute convergence.

Comment: No, your original estimate will not work for the absolute series.

Comment: Well, graphing the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert \sin k \rvert$, it definitely diverges, so I would not be able to use Dirichlet's test again.

Comment: @dustin: It seems that your suggested duplicate is not quite the same as this one. That one did not deal with the absolute convergence case.

Comment: @john the post has been edited and changed a few times since I made that vote.

Comment: ic... thanks for the clarification. @dustin

Comment: When $p=1$, it is not absolutely convergent. See one of the answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15984/does-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-sin-nn1-frac12-cdots-frac1n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out, Dirichlet test takes care of convergence, whatever $p$.

Regarding absolute convergence, comparison test implies $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\sin n}{n^p}$ is absolutely convergent whenever $p>1$.

Concerning, $p=1$, the series diverges absolutely (see this [How to prove that $ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N} } | \frac{\sin( n)}{n} | $ diverges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264980/how-to-prove-that-sum-n-in-mathbbn-frac-sin-nn-diverges))

This solves the rest of the problem: if $p<1$, $\left|\frac{\sin(n)}{n^p}\right|\geq | \frac{\sin( n)}{n} |$ and comparison test yields divergence.